# QTP11 How to use generated setting vbs script?

Tags: qtp

I downloaded `QTP version 11` for the first time to see what is `QTP`.
I'm using Web, ActiveX add-on to test web application.

I looked thru help documentation and but not able to find my answer.

**File > Settings > Properties tab**,

there is **"Generated Script"** to generate vbs file for setting.

Inside looks like:

```
Dim App 'As Application
Set App = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
App.Launch
App.Visible = True
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Web").Active = True
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Web").Browser = "IE"
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Web").Address = "http://www.w3schools.com/Html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target"
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Web").CloseOnExit = True

...continue
```

So now I have this vbs file that I want to apply the setting for my test. How can I do it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation for the **Generate Script** button?

> Generates a QuickTest automation script containing the current test
> settings.
>
> When you click the **Generate Script** button, a Save As dialog
> box opens, enabling you to specify the name and file system location
> to store the generated file.
>
> You can use some or all of the script
> lines from this generated script in an automation script. This can be
> useful, for example, if you want to open a test with required test
> settings already set or to set the same test settings for multiple
> tests by looping through the tests in a folder.
>
> For details, see
> QuickTest Automation Scripts and the QuickTest Professional Automation
> Object Model Reference (**Help > QuickTest Professional Help > HP
> QuickTest Professional Advanced References > HP QuickTest Professional
> Automation Object Model**).

Comment: I already read through the section but it say it "can" do something but it does not really explain "how" and that's where I am bit confused.

Comment: @masato-san this is relevant for people using AOM i.e. running QTP tests from outside QTP. If you're using QTP directly or via Quality Center you don't have to deal with it.

Comment: Ahh i see.. the doc says I can just configure those settings within QTP interface. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

The vbscript file that QTP/UFT produces does not have the code to run the test.
You have to add the following code to the vbscript file to actually get the test to run when you launch the vbscript from the command console
(code copied from
 http://qtpcode.blogspot.com/2010/06/running-qtp-script-through-vbs-file.html)

```
Dim qtTest 'As QuickTest.Test ' Declare a Test object variable
Dim qtResultsOpt 'As QuickTest.RunResultsOptions ' Declare a Run Results Options object variable For Viewing Results

Set qtTest = App.Test
Set qtResultsOpt = CreateObject("QuickTest.RunResultsOptions") ' Create the Run Results Options object
qtResultsOpt.ResultsLocation = "C:\<location>" ' Set the results location
qtTest.Run qtResultsOpt ' Run the test
qtApp.Options.Run.ViewResults = True

'Close QTP
qtTest.Close ' Close the test

'Set the options to nothing
Set qtResultsOpt = Nothing ' Release the Run Results Options object
Set qtTest = Nothing ' Release the Test object
Set qtApp = Nothing ' Release the Application object
```